# Migrate source code from git to TFVC

Tags: git, tfs, migration, azure-devops, tfvc

We are using visual studio online, and we use the git support of TFS.
We now want to stop using git and use TFVC instead.

What is the best solution to migrate our source code to TFVC ?

Answer (score 2):

Assume you are creating another project in VSO and moving the source code, as per today you cannot change or mix TFVC with Git in the same project.

There is no best solution, but I can recap some techniques.

1. forget about history, pull down and check into the new version control
2. use git-tf (no branch support)
3. use git-tfs
4. use the Integration Platform to sync everything

Option 1 is the simplest, 4 the most complex. Two and three are similar and again depends on the richness of data you want to save.

Comment: Can you point to resources for using git-tfs to migrate git to TFVC?