# Migrating Github Git repo to Azure DevOps TFVC

Tags: git, azure, github, azure-devops, tfvc

I have an existing repository on Github and want to move it to Azure DevOps, but I want to switch version control to TFVC. Is there a good way to do this, and/or is it possible?

I tried using git-tf to check-in my git repository into Azure DevOps, but I keep getting an access denied error.

Comment: `git-tf` is no longer maintained. Look at `git-tfs` instead. One letter makes a big difference.

Comment: How is your problem progressing?

Comment: Following some research and contacting Microsoft Azure DevOps support, I've come to the conclusion that TFVC is mostly a thing of the past and everything is moving towards git. Don't wanna go against the flow, so I'm just going to stay with git.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrate source code from git to TFVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785072/migrate-source-code-from-git-to-tfvc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. AFAIK, you can create a new project with `TFVC` as your version control system and then import your git repository there.

[image: New TFVC Project]

As quoted in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/team-projects?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Frepos%2Ftfvc%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Frepos%2Ftfvc%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops), you might need to rework the permissions to enable access if the TFVC project has been there and was created prior to TFS 2015 Update 1.

Also, as Daniel says, [git-tf](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=gittf) has reached its EOL, so it is recommended to go with [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) instead.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, may I know how I can import my Git Repo to TFVC.  I already create an empty TFVC project on devops organization.  And I clone the Git repo to my local machine and how I can import it to my newly create TFVC project?